# Tennis simulation

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and coding in general, and I would like feedback on this program that I wrote. It simulates a tennis game, based on a players "serv chance" (how likely it is that a player will win the ball). I primarily want feedback directed at how well my program executes the standard tennis rules, but general feedback is also welcome.

EDIT:
Forgot the txt-file. Just copy-paste this into a txt:

```
One,0,0,0.5  
Two,0,0,0.5
```

The file is structed as: Name, Won Games, Played Games, Serv Chance

```py
import random
from typing import List

class Players: #define class players
    ratio = 0
    def __init__(self, name, winningProb, wonGames, playedGames):
        self.name = name
        self.winningProb = winningProb
        self.wonGames = wonGames
        self.playedGames = playedGames
        if playedGames == 0:
            self.ratio = 0
        else:
            self.ratio = self.wonGames/self.playedGames
        self.score = 0
    def showPlayerInfo(self):
        print(self.name, self.wonGames, self.playedGames, self.winningProb)
    def playerInfo(self, position): 
        return [str(position), self.name, str(self.wonGames), str(self.playedGames), str(self.winningProb)]
    def getWinningProb(self):
        return self.winningProb
    def getScore(self):
        return self.score
    def setScore(self, score):
        self.score = score
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getWonGames(self):
        return self.wonGames
    def getPlayedGames(self):
        return self.playedGames

def isInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False        
        

def readPlayers(): #reads data from "players.txt" and stores it in player
    fil = open("players.txt","r")
    data = fil.read()
    n = data.count(",")
    fil.close()
    if n > 5:
        txtinfo = open("players.txt", "r")
        players = []
        for row in txtinfo:
            infoPlayers = row.split(",")
            players.append(Players(infoPlayers[0], float(infoPlayers[3]), int(infoPlayers[1]), int(infoPlayers[2])))
        txtinfo.close
        return players
    else: 
        print("players.txt does not seem to exist or contains unreasonable data.")
        raise SystemExit(0)

def playersSortedWithBoardPlacement(players):
    playersSorted = sorted(players, key=lambda x: x.ratio, reverse = True)
    return playersSorted

def prettyPrint(headers: List[str], data: List[List[str]], separator: str = "  ") -> None:              
    columnWidth = [len(s) for s in headers]                        
    for row in data:                                                                        
        cwidth = [len(s) for s in row]     

        
        columnWidth = [max(ow, cw) for ow, cw in zip(
            columnWidth, cwidth)]           

    prints = [headers] + data
    for row in prints:
        # Pad the data in each cell to the correct width
        row_print = [cell.ljust(cwid) for cwid, cell in zip(columnWidth, row)]
        print(separator.join(row_print))

def displayPlayersList(players):  
    print()
    h = ["Placement", "Name", "Won", "Played", "winningProb"]
    resultatList = []
    position = 1
    for i in players:
        resultatList.append(i.playerInfo(position=position)) 
        position += 1

    prettyPrint(h, resultatList) 

def choosePlayers(players):
    chosenPlayers = []
    counter = 0
    print()
    print("Choose two players from the players list by entering their board placement in integer.")
    x = input("Enter player number for 1st player. ")
    while (not isInt(x)) or int(x) > len(players) or int(x) <= 0:
        x = input("Wrong input. Please enter player number again ")
    x = int(x)
    chosenPlayers.append(players[x-1])
    y = input("Enter player number for 2nd player. ")
    while (not isInt(y)) or int(x)==int(y) or int(y) > len(players) or int(y) <= 0:
        y = input("Wrong input. Please enter player number again ")
    y = int(y)
    chosenPlayers.append(players[y-1])
    return chosenPlayers
    

#returns playerNumber if it won
def isWonTheBall(servingPlayer):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if 0<x and x<servingPlayer.getWinningProb():
        return True
    return False

def checkGameWinner(players):
    if players[0].getScore() == 4 and players[1].getScore() <= 2:
        return 1
    if players[1].getScore() == 4 and players[0].getScore() <= 2:
        return 2
    if players[1].getScore() > 2 and players[0].getScore() > 2:
        if players[1].getScore() >= players[0].getScore()+2:
            return 2
        elif players[0].getScore() >= players[1].getScore()+2:
            return 1
    return 0


def playGame(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, flag, pauseAfterBalls):
    ballCounter = 0
    while True:
        if flag == 1:
            flag = 2
            if isWonTheBall(players[0]):
                players[0].setScore(players[0].getScore() + 1)
            else:
                players[1].setScore(players[1].getScore() + 1)
        elif flag == 2:
            flag == 1
            if isWonTheBall(players[1]):
                players[1].setScore(players[1].getScore() + 1)
            else:
                players[0].setScore(players[0].getScore() + 1)
        ballCounter += 1
        if displayBoardPerBall:
            print("\nBall scores until now")
            print(players[0].name, players[0].getScore())
            print(players[1].name, players[1].getScore())
            print()
        if pauseAfterBalls ==  ballCounter:
            ballCounter = 0
            nothing = input("Game Paused. Enter Any Letter To Continue.")
        #whoWon stores 0 if nobody won
        whoWon = checkGameWinner(players)
        if whoWon!=0:
            print("\n\nPlayer",whoWon+1,"won this game.")
            players[0].setScore(0)
            players[1].setScore(0)
            return whoWon
        if players[0].getScore() == 3 and players[1].getScore() == 3:
            print("\nDEUCE!!\n")

def whoWillServeFirst():
    return random.randint(1,2)

def isEven(num):
    if num%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isOdd(num):
    if num%2!=0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def playSet(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, pauseAfterBalls, pauseAfterGames):
    player1Wins = 0
    player2Wins = 0
    gameCounter = 0
    counter = 1
    unflag = 0
    #this flag tells who will serve first in the first game
    flag = whoWillServeFirst()
    #flag is odd server i.e 1,3,5. Unflag is even server i.e 2,4,6
    if flag == 1:
        unflag = 2
    else:
        unflag == 1
    while True:
        print("\nGame #",counter,"starts now.")
        counter+=1
        gameCounter += 1
        if isEven(gameCounter):
            server = unflag
        elif isOdd(gameCounter):
            server = flag
        x = playGame(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, server, pauseAfterBalls)
        if x == 1:
            player1Wins += 1
        elif x == 2:
            player2Wins += 2
        if displayBoardPerGame:
            print("\nGame scores until now")
            print(players[0].name, player1Wins)
            print(players[1].name, player2Wins)
        gameCounter += 1
        if gameCounter == pauseAfterGames:
            gameCounter = 0
            nothing = input("Set Paused. Enter Any Letter To Continue.")
            
        #once a player has won 6 games and is at least 2 games ahead, they wins the match
        if player1Wins > 5 and player1Wins >= player2Wins+2:
            return 1
        elif player2Wins > 5 and player2Wins >= player1Wins+2:
            return 2

def play3Sets(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, pauseAfterBalls, pauseAfterGames):
    player1Wins = 0
    player2Wins = 0
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print("\nSet #", counter, "starts now.")
        x = playSet(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, pauseAfterBalls, pauseAfterGames)
        if x == 1:
            player1Wins += 1
        elif x == 2:
            player2Wins += 1
        print("\nSet scores until now")
        print(players[0].name, player1Wins)
        print(players[1].name, player2Wins)
        #winning 2 sets first wins you the match
        if player1Wins >= 2:
            return players[0]
        elif player2Wins >= 2:
            return players[1]

def updateTextFiles(winner, players, totalPlayers):
    f = open("players.txt", "w")
    i = 0
    playerString = []
    for ele in totalPlayers:
        if ele.getName() == winner.getName():
            playerString.append(str(ele.getName()+','+str(int(ele.getWonGames()+1))+','+str((int(ele.getPlayedGames())+1))+','+str(ele.getWinningProb()) +'\n'))
        elif ele.getName() == players[0].getName() or ele.getName()==players[1].getName():
            playerString.append(str(ele.getName()+','+str(ele.getWonGames())+','+str((int(ele.getPlayedGames())+1))+','+str(ele.getWinningProb())+'\n'))
        else:
            playerString.append(str(ele.getName()+','+str(ele.getWonGames())+','+str(ele.getPlayedGames())+','+str(ele.getWinningProb())+'\n'))
        i+=1
    f.writelines(playerString)

def play():
    print("WELCOME! The tennis simulation is about to start.\n")
    totalPlayers = readPlayers()
    totalPlayers = playersSortedWithBoardPlacement(totalPlayers)
    displayPlayersList(totalPlayers)
    #choosing players who'll play the game
    players = choosePlayers(totalPlayers)
    print("\n")
    while True:
        flag = input("Do you want to view the scoreboards after every ball?(y/n) ")
        if flag == 'y' or flag == 'Y':
            displayBoardPerBall = True
            print("Displays result after every ball.")
            break
        if flag == 'n' or flag == 'N':
            displayBoardPerBall = False
            print("Does NOT display result after every ball.")
            break
        print("Wrong input.")
    flag =''
    while True:
        flag = input("Do you want to view the scoreboards after every game?(y/n) ")
        if flag == 'y' or 'Y':
            displayBoardPerGame = True
            print("Displays result after every game.")
            break
        if flag == 'n' or 'N':
            displayBoardPerGame = False
            print("Does NOT display result after every ball.")
            break
        print("Wrong input.")

    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("After how many *balls* do you want to pause the game? (Range 1-4). Enter 0 to continue without pausing. "))
            if x == 0:
                pauseAfterBalls = float('inf')
                break
            if x>0 and x<5:
                pauseAfterBalls = x
                break
            print("Wrong input. Try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong input. Try again.")
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("After how many *games* do you want to pause the game? (Range 1-4). Enter 0 to continue without pausing. "))
            if x == 0:
                pauseAfterGames = float('inf')
                break
            if x>0 and x<5:
                pauseAfterGames = x
                break
            print("Wrong input. Try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong input. Try again.")
    winner = play3Sets(players, displayBoardPerBall, displayBoardPerGame, pauseAfterBalls, pauseAfterGames)
    updateTextFiles(winner, players, totalPlayers)
    newResult = readPlayers()
    print("\n\nCongratulations player", winner.name, "\nYou won the match.\n")
    displayPlayersList(newResult)
play()
```

Comment: `No such file or directory: 'players.txt'`

Comment: Edited post, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: no problem, we all forget things

Answer (score 2):

### Listing members

```
def playerInfo(self, position): 
    return [str(position), self.name, str(self.wonGames), str(self.playedGames), str(self.winningProb)]
```

This method's name is misleading. It seems like you're making an attempt at tabular output, which is reasonable; but you're going about it in a somewhat awkward way. You're probably better off calling this something like `as_row`, and omitting position since it has nothing to do with the class instance. You can append this externally; this loop:

```
resultatList = []
position = 1
for i in players:
    resultatList.append(i.playerInfo(position=position)) 
    position += 1

prettyPrint(h, resultatList)
```

can become

```py
result_list = []

for position, player in enumerate(players, 1):
    result_list.append([str(position), *player.as_row()])

pretty_print(headers, result_list)
```

### Getters

All of these:

```
def getWinningProb(self):
    return self.winningProb
def getScore(self):
    return self.score
def setScore(self, score):
    self.score = score
def getName(self):
    return self.name
def getWonGames(self):
    return self.wonGames
def getPlayedGames(self):
    return self.playedGames
```

need to be deleted. This isn't Java - there is no enforced public or private, and the convention is that if a member is set without a leading underscore, it's simply publicly accessible.

### Is-integer

For your purposes, this entire method `isInt` can be replaced with `str.isnumeric()`. But you don't even need that; this loop:

```
x = input("Enter player number for 1st player. ")
while (not isInt(x)) or int(x) > len(players) or int(x) <= 0:
    x = input("Wrong input. Please enter player number again ")
x = int(x)
```

can be

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter player number for 1st player. "))
        if 0 <= x < len(players):
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass

    print('Wrong input.')
```

### Safe file closing

```
fil = open("players.txt","r")
data = fil.read()
n = data.count(",")
fil.close()
```

will leave a file handle dangling if `read` or `count` throw an exception. The solution is to use a `with` context manager:

```
with open('players.txt') as fil:
    data = fil.read()

n = data.count(',')
```

You re-open it as `txtinfo` - don't do this; simply keep the existing `fil` open and move your player info parsing code within the `with` block. You'll probably need to seek to the beginning after your `read()` call.

### Exiting

```
    raise SystemExit(0)
```

is a very strange way of saying

```
exit(0)
```

and you should probably just do the latter.

### Grammar, PEP8

`isWonTheBall` should just be `won_the_ball`. CamelCase is discouraged in favour of lower_snake_case for method and variable names.

### Combined inequalities

```
if 0<x and x<servingPlayer.getWinningProb():
```

can be

```
if 0 < x < serving_player.get_winning_prob():
```

### isEven

Use boolean expression values directly:

```
def isEven(num):
    if num%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be

```
def is_even(num: int) -> bool:
    return num%2 == 0
```

Also note the use of signature type hints.

There's a lot more, but this should get you a start.

Comment: it is post id 252525 :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 ha, neat. I was particularly proud when I accidentally filed ticket #33333 at work a few months back.

Comment: Incredible detailed answer! Thank you. I haven't had a chance to go through it just yet, but will do asap.